# Plot table function objects with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, geom-bar

I've got this data:

```
table(main$Sex1,main$District)

        Bahawalnagar Barkhan Chiniot  Faisalabad Ghotki 
Female    37           16       26       97         46          
Male      25           19       15       20         25
```

I can plot it with base R

```
barplot(table(main$Sex1,main$District))
```

So my question is, how can I do this with ggplot2? Thanks

Comment: Ggplot2 works the best with date in the 'long' format, your table is in `wide`. Can you provide a `dput` from `main`?

Comment: @Wimpel Dear could you please elaborate what do you need I am new to R. Thanks

Comment: read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @wimpel `table` class is already long, it just prints in a special way. If you pass it with `as.data.frame` it will be long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(main$Sex1,main$District)), aes(Var1, Freq, fill=Var2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

table class is long, but it  prints in a special way, and ggplot doesn't know how to handle it. If you pass it with as.data.frame it will be perfectly manageable by ggplot.

Comment: I found this is also working Thanks 
p <-ggplot(main, aes(main$District))
p +geom_bar(aes(fill = Sex1))

Comment: Yes, that's the more straightforward approach :) you can drop the "main$" inside the `aes`.